# HdInsight Service - Jupyter notebook Issue

Tags: azure, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, azure-hdinsight

I have deployed a HDInsight 3.6 Spark (2.3) cluster on Microsoft Azure with the standard configurations (Location = Central US, Head Nodes = D12 v2 (x2) - 8 cores, Worker Nodes = D13 v2 (x4)) - 32 cores).

2. Launch Jupyter notebook and when selecting spark notebook gives a weird error which i am not able to figure out .

Any help on this please

[image: Jupyter Notebook Issue]

Answer (score 1):

Please try below steps to resolve this issue.

1. Connect to headnode via ssh and change content of file - `/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbformat/_version.py`, replace 5 to 4.

[image]

Change this to:

> version_info = (4, 0, 3)

[image]

2. Restart Jupyter service via Ambari.

[image]

*Reference*:[HDInshight Create not create Jupyter notebook](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8c763fb4-79a9-496f-a75c-44a125e934ac/hdinshight-create-not-create-jupyter-notebook?forum=hdinsight#4e9cf0cf-78c7-4a0d-95f5-d4c40c6f4727)